# Allow Unauthenticated ASP.NET MVC 3 User in Window Authenticated Intranet Site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, intranet

I'm trying to create an intranet template site with asp.net mvc 3 which allows windows authenticated users to login and view the site, and unauthenticated users to of the site, but less of it.

My question is similar to this one:  [Using Windows Authentication with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343209/using-windows-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc) I've tried the solution, my web.config file is set to windows authentication.  I'm using Authorize attributes when necessary, but the problem seems even when I have no Authorize attributes unauthenticated (public) users cannot view the page the controller serves.

The answer on that post suggests, but to no avail.

> Any controllers without an [Authorize] attribute should be open to the public automatically. So, only put your attribute on the controllers you want to lock down.

Perhaps because I'm using MVC 3, and not MVC 2 I may be getting different results, but I cannot find an answer.

This links may also be helpful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(v=vs.98).aspx
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-vb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the settings for IIS to allow anonymous access rather than changing anything in your controller.

Comment: Didn't work for me, but I figured a way around it.  We just created a dummy user with a simple password.  I don't want to fiddle with it anymore. Thanks though.